# How to set Qualifier on an Implementation that has an interface which extends another interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have 2 Interfaces A and B which extends another Interface C. However when i  use the @Qualifier("aImpl") i get a unsatisfactionary dependency from spring

The interfaces

```
public interface EsResourceLoader { ... }

public interface CommonEsDao extends EsResourceLoader { ... }

public interface CommonModifiedEsDao extends EsResourceLoader { ... }
```

The first implementation

```
@Service
public class LBModifiedEsDao implements CommonModifiedEsDao { ... }
```

The second implementation

```
@Service
public class LBDao implements CommonEsDao { 

  private CommonModifiedEsDao myDao;

  @Autowired
  public LBDao(@Qualifier("lBModifiedEsDao") CommonModifiedEsDao myDao) { ... 
  }
}
```

The controller throwing the exception

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping{...}
public class IndexAdminController {

  private CommonEsDao esDao;

  @Autowired
  public IndexAdminController(@Qualifier("lBDao")CommonEsDao esDao){ ... }


}
```

And here is the Exception

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh 
attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'indexAdminController': Unsatisfied dependency 
expressed through field 'lbDao';
```

Comment: Your `indexAdminController` doesn't have a field `lbDao`. Are you sure that code matches exception? Could it be that your controller is in older version?

Comment: its not about field i think its about name resolving  , maybe you can put @Service("lbDao") and then try it again

Answer (score 0):

Put your @Qualifier annotation to service and it should works.

```
@Service
@Qualifier("lBModifiedEsDao") 
public class LBModifiedEsDao
implements CommonModifiedEsDao { ... }
```

And also for second service

```
@Service
@Qualifier("lBDao")
public class LBDao implements CommonEsDao { 

  private CommonModifiedEsDao myDao;

  @Autowired
  public LBDao(@Qualifier("lBModifiedEsDao") CommonModifiedEsDao myDao) { ... 
  }
}
```

Now Spring should be able to always autowire it correctly. Also this is also nice because you can be sure with that you will have always correct implementation.

EDIT: As I did in your code with `@Qualifier` annotation can be achieved by using name in Component annotations, ie.: `@Component("myComponent")`